# ¿Duda con funciones propias en ModelAdmin, Django?

Tags: django, django-admin

Tengo una duda en el momento de registrar un modelo en `Django` con su correspondiente configuración extendida me refiero al `PostAdmin`, antes que nada aquí el código de los modelos:

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils.timezone import now
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

# Create your models here.

class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 100, verbose_name = 'Nombre')
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = True, verbose_name = 'Fecha de Creasion')
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now = True, verbose_name = 'Fecha de Edicion')

    class Meta():
        ordering = ['-created']

        verbose_name = 'categoria'
        verbose_name_plural = 'categorias'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length = 200, verbose_name = 'Titulo')
    content = models.TextField(verbose_name = 'Contenido')
    published = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name = 'Fecha de publicasion', default = now)
    image = models.ImageField(verbose_name = 'Imagen', upload_to = 'blog', null = True, blank = True)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, verbose_name = 'Autor', on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    categories = models.ManyToManyField(Category, verbose_name = 'Categorias')
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = True, verbose_name = 'Fecha de Creasion')
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now = True, verbose_name = 'Fecha de Edicion')

    class Meta():
        verbose_name = "Post"
        verbose_name_plural = "Posts"

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

Mi duda es con la función `post_categories`, bueno lo que hace la función es retornar las categorías de un Post. aquí el código del `admin.py`:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Category, Post

# Register your models here.

class CategoryAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    readonly_fields = ['created', 'updated']

class PostAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    readonly_fields = ['created', 'updated']
    list_display = ['title', 'author', 'published', 'post_categories']
    ordering = ['author', 'published']
    search_fields = ['title', 'author__username', 'categories__name']
    date_hierarchy = 'published'
    list_filter = ['author__username', 'categories__name']

    def post_categories(self, obj):
        return ', '.join([c.name for c in obj.categories.all().order_by('name')])

admin.site.register(Category, CategoryAdmin)
admin.site.register(Post, PostAdmin)
```

Y bueno mi pregunta es ¿Como la función `post_categories` recibe el parametro `obj`? y ¿De que manera se envía el objeto a la función `post_categories`?

**Bueno desde ya gracias por sus respuestas!**

Comment: Hola, lo primero es que dentro de las clases a las _funciones_ se les conoce como _métodos_ no es algo muy relevante, pero a futuro puede ayudarte a evitar confusiones. No entiendo muy bien cual es el sentido de tu pregunta, porque quizá si quieres saber la forma en la que el código le envía el objeto a ese _método_ puedes leer el código directamente desde GitHub. Del resto el administrador de Django ya está apto para a partir del parámetro dado en la url obtener un objeto específico, o recorriendo un queryset puede hacer esto: `self.post_categories(x) for x in Post.objects.all()`

Comment: Osea el objeto que se manda al método `post_categories` es: `Post.objects.all()`

Comment: No, viene siendo o bien el Post que recoge con el `id` que sale en la url, o el post que resulta de recorrer el queryset. Es decir, `Post.objects.all()` es una lista de `Post` (un queryset), entonces el `obj` que te llega como parámetro, solo es 1 `Post` de esa lista, de acuerdo a la iteración

Comment: Entonces `Django` me manda algo asi: `Post.objects.get(pk=1)`, por cada post creado, con su correspondiente `pk`?

Comment: Puede ser de esa forma o de la otra que te dije que es casi la misma. Si quieres verificar puedes dentro del método correr esto: `print(isinstance(obj, Post))` y mira que te retorna

Comment: Ok muchas gracias por ayudarme!